# Retrieving data from python mongo db

Tags: python, pymongo

I have inserted

```
{
   "apples": 430,
   "bananas": 312,
   "oranges": 525,
   "pears": 217
}
```

to mongodb in python. However, I tried a lot ways to get value by key

If I want to get values for "apple", how would I achieve that?

Comment: Are you using the official module for Python and MongoDB (PyMongo) or an alternative module to access your database?

Comment: Are you using a framework (e.g. Flask, Django, etc.)?

Comment: hi, I am not using any framework. I am just using regular Python.  I followed tutorial http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html  but could not find anything that solves my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values in MongoDB are stored in a json format.
If you want to query from a MongoDB database, I'd recommend using PyMongo.
I'll assume you can read by yourself how to connect to the database.
The query you're looking for is as follows

```
apples = db.collection.distinct("base.apples")
result = db.collection.distinct("result")
```

In case apples shows in other places, ofcourse.

Comment: @SamThapa I'm glad!